# Django - error from call to values_list: 'flat' is not defined

Tags: python, django

Here's a loop I'm using to process an Excel sheet with `openpyxl`. On occasion the `partno` field is missing and I try to derive it from another database table (`booking`) using a field called `transmittal`. I'm having trouble with this lookup and it returns an error. When I run the same thing under the Django shell, it works fine.

```
parser = parse_defrev(book)
brs = []
xmtl_part = {}
invalid = []
for r in parser.process():
    # If no partno, try to look it up in the bookings table
    if r.get('partno') is None:
        xmtl = r.get('transmittal')
        if xmtl:
            r['partno'] = xmtl_part.get(xmtl)
            if not r['partno']:
                parts = set(Booking.objects.filter(bookingtransmittal=r['transmittal']).values_list('bookingpartno', flat=True))
                if len(parts) == 1:
                    r['partno'] = parts.pop()
                    xmtl_part[xmtl] = r['partno']
```

`process` is a generator function in the `parse_defrev` class which returns a dictionary with the processed fields from the workbook. If `partno` is missing, then it first tries to retrieve it from a caching dictionary and then from the `booking` table. The `values_list` returns any matching `partno` values, and if there is more than 1 match it just logs the problem and skips to the next row.

I get the following error, and don't understand how it could fail to recognize the `flat` keyword.

```
    parts = set(Booking.objects.filter(bookingtransmittal=r['transmittal']).values_list('bookingpartno', flat=True))
    NameError: name 'flat' is not defined
```

However it works in the Django shell, after importing Booking, I do this.

```
>>> r = dict()
>>> r['transmittal'] = '21/05 01'
>>> parts = set(Booking.objects.filter(bookingtransmittal=r['transmittal']).values_list('bookingpartno', flat=True))
```

& irrespective of whether there are zero or more fields in the lookup result, it returns the expected result, which is a set containing the part numbers.

Python 3.9.5, Django 3.2.4, Windows client under Visual Studio Code with git bash shell, to CentOS PostgreSQL back end.

There's an easy workaround, which is a simple change, but I'd still like to understand why the flat keyword isn't recognized here.

```
                parts = set(Booking.objects.filter(bookingtransmittal=r['transmittal']).values_list('bookingpartno'))
                if len(parts) == 1:
                    r['partno'] = parts.pop()[0]
```

Comment: well, that looks weird. is that an exact code with original indentation and line breaks?

Comment: Yes. It is very weird. That small modification of changing `values_list` to `values`, removing `flat=True` and adding `[0]` to `parts.pop()` runs without error and produces the expected result, so I think the indentation is ok.